com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher.com.facebook.react.uimanager.UiManagerModule.getEventDispatcher() on a null object reference
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';

const Registration = () => {
    const cameraRef = useRef(null);
    const [cameraReady, setCameraReady] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Handle camera initialization and permissions here
        if (cameraRef.current) {
            setCameraReady(true);
        }
    }, [cameraRef]);

    const handleCameraReady = () => {
        setCameraReady(true);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {cameraReady ? (
                <RNCamera
                    ref={cameraRef}
                    style={styles.preview}
                    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
                    flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
                    androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
                        title: 'Permission to use camera',
                        message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
                        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    }}
                    onCameraReady={handleCameraReady}
                />
            ) : (
                <Text>Camera is initializing...</Text>
            )}
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
    preview: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});

export default Registration;

Getting error in react native v0.76 when try to use react-native-camera Review My Error is Below
Attempt to invoke vitual method 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher.com.facebook.react.uimanager.UiManagerModule.getEventDispatcher()' on a null object reference

facing the same issue since some days. I wasnt able to find this question anywhere on the internet.

I got this resolved by adding the permissions in the android.manifest file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
